# Are [feed] and [feeds] both feeding from the same trough?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feed)

> A web feed is a data format used for providing users with frequently updated content.

[feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feeds)

> A feed (or news feed) is a data format used for providing users with frequently updated content.

[news-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news-feed) probably means the same, too, but it has no tag excerpt.

I think [feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feeds) (and possibly [news-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news-feed)) should be retagged with [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feed).

If the term "feed" is too ambiguous, we could consider renaming the tag to [web-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-feed), [which is what the Wikipedia article calls it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed).